# how to use keyclaok in multi-tenant application

Tags: realm, keycloak

I have a web application on which I am hosting some events like hosting a business meeting every week and these events are isolated from each other each event will have its own users and for their authentication and authorization, I want to use KeyCloak so in the KeyClaok context my client will be my web app and I will add the event users in keycloak now for the event part should I create a separate realm for each event? like I have a business meeting on 21st of May and the on 29th of May, so do I need to create new realms per event and add metting participants as a user in KeyCloak? please guide me on this do i need to create a realm per event or there is some other approach i can use ?

Comment: There are a thousand approaches you can use; which one you choose will depend on the types of queries you want to run, overall security and lastly how you want the data accessed. The question title says 'multi-tenant' but the description does not match. Perhaps you mean multi-user, not multi-tenant? Also, asking for opinions is off-topic for SO so please ask a specific coding question, include the code you've attempted and  clarify what's being asked. We'll take a look and see if we can help!

Comment: its a multi-tenant each event is isolated from another event, also i am not asking for opinion i am asking what keyclaok offer in this scanerio ,hope it clears my concern

Comment: *should I create a separate realm for each event* is asking for our opinion and without knowing the entire use case, the would depend on how that data is being used. Also just having isolated *events* is not really multi-tenant; Multi tenant applications serve numerous *customers* within one app. The architecture of the app keeps data totally separate, including users, events, data etc. Every client is known as a tenant. Also, you've tagged the question with Realm (the database) and that doesn't have anything to do with Keycloak which has it's own 'keycloak realm'. Keycloaks database is H2.